# PowerPoint Interop Assemblies Slowness Issue

Tags: c#, vb.net, interop, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm using MS Office interop assemblies to build a Powerpoint addin that inserts slides and charts on the fly. But during insertion it take up to 20 seconds to complete the process from inserting the slide to insertion of the chart.

After doing extensive logging, I noticed few lines of code where our application gets stuck for 20+ seconds.
Here are those lines:

```
powerpointChartObj.SetSourceData(Source:=String.Format("=Sheet1!A1:B{0}", 5))

powerpointSlideObject.Shapes("some shape name")
```

We continuously play with PowerPoint chart and slide objects during the slide insertion process but some time it gets blocked on one of above lines. And it's random on which line it gets blocked.

**Following are the office libraries we are using:**

1. Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
2. Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
3. Microsoft Graph 16.0 Object Library
4. Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library
5. Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library
6. Microsoft.Office.Tools.dll
7. Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.dll
8. Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll
9. Microsoft.Office.Tools.v4.0.Framework.dll
10. Microsoft.Vbe.Interop

**Test Environemnt**

Office 2016

Windows 8.1 + Windows 10

16 GB RAM, Intel Core i5-4570 CPU

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated.

PS. Also tried using Office 15.0 Object libraries

**Updated**

I've tried EnableEvents and set it false forever. It boost up the performance during chart insertion/update scenarios but if we continuously make calls to PowerPoint COM components(e.g. Shapes, slides etc. to manipulate PowerPoint things), PowerPoint gets stuck for around 20 seconds again. Not sure if there is anything similar to EnableEvents available in PowerPoint interop.

Comment: Does the problem code run on a secondary thread?  Is the thread it runs on a STAThread or MTAThread?

Comment: It's running on default main thread. Nothing special is specified.

Comment: Delays that long are almost always environment problems.  Temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product.  And beware of page file thrashing, a pretty likely problem here.   Use Task Manager, Processes tab and ensure you don't see a large amount of orphaned Excel.exe or Winword.exe processes.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. Disabling windows defender real-time protection doesn't help. System specifications are updated in question. Also noticed that when Excel program is already open things gets done in 3-4 seconds. But still that's a huge time for desktop application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the rights to comment yet, so bear with me if this is not the perfect answer.

My experience with automation with office products is through VBS, but they both uses the COM-objects, so it probably works the same. I mostly use Excel, so powerpoint is not my strongest side.

My suggestion is to temporary disable screenupdates/events while adding data.

Here is an example (using VBS):

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'Excel specific
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'All office products
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False 'All office products
Application.EnableEvents = False 'All office products
'your code running here
Application.EnableEvents = True 'All office products
Application. DisplayStatusBar = True 'All office products
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'All office products
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'Excel specific
```

Also avoid using a lot "select" calls in data, since it slows things down.

In my VBS scripts I got more or less no lag or problems by using this technique. I would also suggest that you create your own "please wait" popup screen while adding alot of data. For some calls do take time, even if you do it manually in Powerpoint / Excel.

Good luck, office automation can be a hazzle :)

Comment: Just a tip, record what the Calculation mode is to a variable (it maybe set xlCalculationManual) and set it back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, appreciate that. I've tried EnableEvents and set it false forever. It boost up the performance but if we continuously make calls to PowerPoint COM components(e.g. Shapes, slides etc.), PowerPoint gets stuck for around 20 seconds again. Upvoted the answer, hope you can comment now :)

Comment: In some events the autosave feature could make some hazzle, try temporary disable that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/how-autosave-impacts-addins-and-macros

Others in the office have tested to temporary remove the "undo" function, https://www.isumsoft.com/office/change-how-many-undos-you-can-perform-in-powerpoint.html that is typical on low end hardware

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback. I commented out all code from BeforeSave and many other PowerPoint events e.g. OnNewSlide, WindowsSelectionChanged etc. Now I'm only inserting the slide on button click and during insertion I add chart to that slide and do some modification with slide shapes in the meanwhile. I set the Application.EnableEvents = False and never set it back to True. But still after inserting some slides (around 5-10) PowerPoint gets stuck for 20 seconds on this line: gWorkBook = tempChartObject.ChartData.Workbook

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce on my work laptop but I can't get it behave like you describe. Each slide is probably linked to a Excel-workbook through each chart. So the error for hanging could be in either Excel or Powerpoint. Atm I don't have any good suggestions for you. But I'll keep it in my mind if something comes up :)

Comment: A colleague gave me a tip to try to pause for just 1 second after each chart is placed, to ensure that office automation have time to finish their background tasks.