# Interop PowerPoint Chart Alternative

Tags: c#, vba, vb.net, powerpoint, office-interop

As we know inserting chart in PowerPoint presentation is quite slow and painful task using PowerPoint Interop assemblies. It not only opens up the unnecessary Excel window 
that we have to tackle but also it takes some considerable amount of time to completely insert the chart.

Taking care of Excel instances can be sometimes very painful task and it may lead to application crashes and slowness of PowerPoint addin itself.

So my question is: Is there any alternative(s) to PowerPoint Interop charts that can be incorporated into PowerPoint Addin.

Any feedback or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the way that you are using the interops please?

Comment: powerPointSlide.Shapes.AddChart(XlChartType.xlBarClustered, 0, 0, 100, 100). powerPointSlide is PowerPoint.Slide class object. This line takes 500-700 miliseconds and opens up an excel instance.

Comment: Can you show the class in the original code, so can see how you are using the interops rather than class. Cheers.

Comment: What kind of powerpoint add-in? Faster would certainly be to leverage the Office Open XML file format using, for example, the Open XML SDK. In PowerPoint this can be done only on the closed file, however...

Comment: I'm using PowerPoint VSTO addin with interop assemblies. Open XML could be an option but I've to work with opened file in real time instead of closed file.

Comment: If someone wants to discuss performance issues, I've a separate issue opened for that, with BOUNTY... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004405/powerpoint-interop-assemblies-slowness-issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to go that route, you can use Office Open XML Sdk to generate the files directly. It's quite efficient to do that compared to Interop (milliseoncds vs minutes runtime...) but it is a lot of work to program.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

If you want to use that, use an abstraction library with helps with the excel files, though - doing them by hand is a royal pain.